How do I bake my image texture which has a layer weight node?
I have been trying to bake this texture using combined bake and transmission bake but nothing is working, here is my shader nodes:

As you can see I have tried many different BSDFs and alterantives to the layer weight but nothing works, what should I do? Is it even possible to bake something with a transparent BSDF or a layer weight?

Layer weights rely on the view angle.
You have to change bake view to active camera

This will bake it based on what you see from the camera


But since it's baked it wont hold up if you view the object from any view outside of the camera.


Where is this option "View from"? For some reason I only have the bake type and that's it, then it continues to the influence panel

What version of blender are you using?
